# why the flash is turned off when the screen is turned off?

Tags: android, flash

my app is a simple torch, it works fine, but when the phone turned off the flash light is turned off too, I want to make it turned on till I turn it off by the app or kill the app...
then I want to ask if its possible to turn off the flash by this app if its turned on by another app, and vice versa...
here is my code:

```
package com.example.flash;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class FlashLight extends Activity {

    ImageButton l;
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
    final Context context = this;
    Camera.Parameters cp;
    boolean flag = false;
    boolean mode = false;
    String OFF = android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF;
    String ON = android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON;
    String TORCH = android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH;
    String AUTO = android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        if(pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)){
            cp = camera.getParameters();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            l = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.l);

                l.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        try{

                            if(cp.getFlashMode().equals(OFF))
                            {
                                lamp(mode);
                            }

                            else if(cp.getFlashMode().equals(TORCH) || cp.getFlashMode().equals(ON))
                            {
                                lamp(mode);
                            }
                        }

                        catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("STACKTRACE:", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                        }
                    }
                });

                a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                         if(camera == null){
                                lamp(mode);
                                }

                             else{
                                lamp(mode);
                                }
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    public void lamp(boolean mode){

        if(!mode){

            if(flag){ 
                camera = Camera.open();
                cp = camera.getParameters();
            }
             playSound(mode);
             cp.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
             camera.setParameters(cp);
             l.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
             this.mode = true;
        }

        else if(mode){

             playSound(mode);
             cp.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
             camera.setParameters(cp);
             camera.release();
             camera = null;
             flag = true;
             l.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
             this.mode = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you lock the phone your activity goes into the onPause() state. So you can try it using the background Service.

By clicking on the start button start the service and put your entire code in background service. Just stop the service by clicking on the stop button. Its a general Idea that a service runs even when your phone is lock.

You can see this link to understand how service works. Its just like an Android Activity with no UI and runs in background. [HERE IT IS](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)